# invalid identifier while creating nested tables

Tags: sql, oracle

im having issues to create nested tables, i've tried to follow the documentation, but i couldn't figure out where's the problem in my syntaxe.

i've already defined tcours,  tevaluation, tetudiant, tenseignant.

```py
create type t_set_ref_cours as table of ref tcours;
create type t_set_ref_evaluation as table of ref tevaluation;
create type t_set_ref_etudiant as table of ref tetudiant;
create type t_set_ref_enseignant as table of ref tenseignant;

create or replace type tcours as object(numero_cours varchar2(5), 
                                        libelle varchar2(50),credit integer, 
                                        est_pre_requis t_set_ref_cours, 
                                        a_pre_requis t_set_ref_cours,
                                        cours_enseigant t_set_ref_enseignant, 
                                        cours_evaluation t_set_ref_evaluation, 
                                        cours_etudiant t_set_ref_etudiant);
/
desc tcours
```

everything is working, this is the output of **desc tcours**.

```
Nom              NULL ? Type                          
---------------- ------ ----------------------------- 
NUMERO_COURS            VARCHAR2(5)                   
LIBELLE                 VARCHAR2(50)                  
CREDIT                  INTEGER()                     
EST_PRE_REQUIS          SYSTEM.T_SET_REF_COURS()      
A_PRE_REQUIS            SYSTEM.T_SET_REF_COURS()      
COURS_ENSEIGANT         SYSTEM.T_SET_REF_ENSEIGNANT() 
COURS_EVALUATION        SYSTEM.T_SET_REF_EVALUATION() 
COURS_ETUDIANT          SYSTEM.T_SET_REF_ETUDIANT()
```

but when i try to create *cours* table

```py
create table cours of tcours (numero_cours primary key)
nested table a_pre_requis     store as table_a_pre_requis,
nested table est_pre_requis   store as table_est_pre_requis,
nested table cours_etudiant   store as table_cours_etudiant,
nested table cours_enseignant store as table_cours_enseignant,
nested table cours_evaluation store as table_cours_evaluation;
/
```

i'm having this error:

```
Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-00904:  : identificateur non valide
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: You have not defined `tevaluation`, `tetudiant`, `tenseignant` so your statements fail. You also need to forward declare `tcours` before you declare `t_set_ref_cours`.

Comment: i did, i just didn't write them, it's too much code, till desc tcours, everything works fine

Comment: You have a typo. In your type `tcours` you declare a field `cours_enseigant`, but in your `create table` statement you refer to it as `cours_enseignant` (with an `n` after the `g`).

Comment: Fix your typo and forward declare `tcours` then it works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9465e64f841933c2b75b2bde3da441a4)

Comment: @LukeWoodward
  thank you so much for reading my code and pointing the error, i spent so much time on it without figuring where was the problem

Comment: @NoviceBL You can just take a systematic approach to solving problems like this (for example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5d5b2ecb676331cc783c4b37f7e6483f)) and then you can solve it yourself.

Comment: oh i see, that's a useful resource!